# Combine like rows based on substring of one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table of parts that looks like this:

| Part | Part Num | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Door | **101053**22 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **101053**23 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **101053**24 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **846251**11 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | **846251**18 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | **846251**85 | abc | abc |  | abc |
| Door | **568971**01 | abc | abc |  |  |

The part number is always 8 characters. For many parts, the first 6 characters are the same, and the last 2 are different. Lines where the first 6 characters of a part number are the same and all rows that have the same values in Thing1/Thing2/Thing3/Thing4 need to be combined, and the part number becomes 6 characters. (row 1/2/3 in the above table)

Lines where the first 6 characters are the same but the values in Thing1/Thing2/Thing3/Thing4 are NOT identical in all rows need to remain unchanged and the part number remains 8 characters. (row 4/5/6 in the above table)

Lines where the first 6 characters are unique need to remain unchanged and the part number remains 8 characters. (row 7 in the above table)

The desired result would look like:

| Part | Part Num | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Door | **101053** | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **846251**11 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | **846251**18 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | **846251**85 | abc | abc |  | abc |
| Door | **568971**01 | abc | abc |  |  |

Comment: I didn't save my SQL from earlier today, but I tried to assign a `DENSE_RANK` on LEFT([Part Num], 2) and partition by all of the other columns, and planned to then use a `CASE`  statement to generate the 6 digit Part Num if the rank value was 1. However, this didn't work for rows 4/5/6 in my example. It assigned the same rank 1 to rows 4/5 and rank 2 to row 6. My original thought was all rows that met the criteria would be assigned a rank of 1, and anything else would get rank 2,3,4,etc but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Part, LEFT(PartNum, 6), Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4) counter1,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Part, LEFT(PartNum, 6)) counter2
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  Part,
  CASE WHEN counter1 > 1 AND counter1 = counter2 THEN LEFT(PartNum, 6) ELSE PartNum END PartNum,
  Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4 
FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b0ddb2e4cf55d2c14931dbd618ba9fc3).

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions to determine what should be combined.  I think I might combine all into a single comparison:

```
select (case when min_thingee = max_thingee and cnt > 1
             then left(partnum, 6) else partnum
        end) as partnum,
       min(thing1) as thing1, min(thing2) as thing2,
       min(thing3) as thing3, min(thing4) as thing4
from (select t.*,
             min(concat(thing1, '|', thing2, '|', thing3, '|', thing4) over (partition by left(partnum, 6)) as min_thingee,
             max(concat(thing1, '|', thing2, '|', thing3, '|', thing4) over (partition by left(partnum, 6)) as max_thingee,
             count(*) over (partition by left(partnum, 6)) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when min_thingee = max_thingee and cnt > 1
               then left(partnum, 6) else partnum
          end);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `dense_rank`, here is one way.

Basic statistics tells us that standard deviation of a set of equal numbers equals 0. This means once we have the rank for each `left(partnum,6)` we can enforce the condition such that we only collapse those groups of rows where --there is only one unique rank AND at least two rows (`stdev` on a single value results in `null` which `<> 0`). Notice the `partition by` clause to see how the ranking is calculated

```
with cte as

(select *, dense_rank() over (order by part, left(partnum,6), thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4) as rnk
 from my_table)

select distinct 
       part,
       case when stdev(rnk) over (partition by part, left(partnum,6)) = 0 then left(partnum,6) else partnum end as partnum,
       thing1,
       thing2,
       thing3,
       thing4
from cte;
```